# Segmenting road polygon layer

Tags: polygon, road

I have a road pavement polygon layer (rose polygon colour). I want to split it at intersections just as a typical center line layer (black lines) is, so that individual street segments can be selected. I have tried buffers, unions, spatial joins, but I have not been successful in using them to segment the layer. Any tips? 
[image]

Comment: What GIS are you using? (looks like arcgis can you confirm)

Comment: There's also the problem of how you would want the pavement in the intersection it self handled, as that's part of both streets.  Would you want a 4-way intersection split with the roads entering the intersection, meaning the intersection would have 4 triangular wedges, or would you want the aprox. square bit making up the intersection a separate polygon from the main road section so the portion that was used by both roads could be selected separately?  Some things to think about before you try splitting it, which will depend on what you need the data for.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure how well this would work and it would depend on the tools that you are using, but the following process may get acceptable result for you.

- Densify the polygon layer boundaries.  Play with the settings.
- Triangulate (Delaunay) the polygon layer.
- Scrap any triangles not covered by the original polygons.
- Distinctly name the triangles by overlaying the centrelines.
- Dissolve/Union the triangles based on the name.

When naming the triangles you will need to decide how you want to handle the intersections.  You may also have some edge cases where triangles are missed by centrelines, etc
As a quick proof of concept I put together a simple FME workspace.  The polygons and lines were very simple ... A cross intersection of 2 uniform roads.
[image]
This gave the following triangulation for the road polygon.
[image]

and the final result was

[image]

Comment: +1 this is what I would suggest. The only thing missing is densify lines of original polygons to create triangles small enough

Answer (score 2):

- Buffer centerlines big enough to cover the underlying polygons - use a buffer with no endcap(advanced license required or can be done in FME)
- Clip buffers with the polygon data
- Union the buffers and polygons
- For intersections - run an intersect on the lines or extract the end nodes
- Buffer the nodes big enough to cover the underlying polygons
- Clip the node buffers with the polygon data
- Union the node buffers and previous union

You'll have to play around with the node buffer size to get the right size for your intersections.